# Use map function for array object and display in table in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array object that looks like this: [image: Array Object]

This is coming from parent component.
I want to display these in a table with all the headings(key) in a single column and their values in other columns. It should look something like this:[image]

I am doing like this:

In my child component I am calling function like this for object coming from parent:

```
  renderYear() {
  if (this.props.total_calculation.length === 0) {
  return null
} else {
  const Year = this.props.total_calculation.map(
    ({ Year }) => Year
  )
  return Year.map(function (d, key) {

    return (
      <td key={key} colSpan="2">
        {(d)}
      </td>
    )

  })

  }
}
```

This is creating td for all the values of each key in the objects(in this function it is year).

And in its render I made a table and render all these tds like this:

```
    <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr className='year'>
              <td>Year</td>
              this.renderYear()
            </tr>
```

I know this is not a good coding way because for each key(like year, rent_increase,...) I have to make a separate function and then render it.

Can you please suggest some efficient way to do this? or if I can optimize the map function.

Comment: Consider attaching the sample of your data as a code, not screenshot to have something to play with.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might not be an optimization problem. What you are searching for is to have only one function that return the render for keys of your object.
Here is a suggestion:

- Change you `renderYear()` method to this:

```
    renderField(objectKey) {
        if (this.props.total_calculation.length === 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return this.props.total_calculation.map(function (obj, key) {
            return (
                <td key={key} colSpan="2">
                    {obj[objectKey]}
                </td>
            );
        });
    }
```

The argument `objectKey` of the `renderField()` method takes as argument a string that is a key of the object you want to render. Then now you can call it like this:

```
        <tr className='year'>
            <td>Year</td>
            {{this.renderField('Year')}}
        </tr>
```

You can call the `renderField()` method on other key of your object like `'rent_increase'`
You should also check the [Open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) of the SOLID principles because your problem has similar solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code,

```
const renderField = () =>
          this.props.total_calculation.length > 0 ? (
          this.props.total_calculation.map(function (obj, key) {
            return (
                <td key={key} colSpan="2">
                    {obj['Year']}
                </td>
            );
        })) : null;
```